# Rename nested properties in complex JSON object

Tags: json, typescript

I have a complex JSON like below:

```
const json = '{"desc":"zzz", "details": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "categoryDetails": { "cid": 1, "name": "abc" } }}'
```

And I need to write logic to rename the keys dynamically. My code looks like below:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

    var renameKeys = [
    { 
        oldKey: 'desc',
        newKey: 'newdesc'
    },
    { 
        oldKey: 'details.name',
        newKey: 'details.newname'
    },
    { 
        oldKey: 'details.categoryDetails.name',
        newKey: 'details.categoryDetails.newname',
    }
];

for (var i in renameKeys) {
    var item = renameKeys[i];
    if(obj[item.oldKey]) { //this throws error - undefined. It is possible that this key does not exist in some objects
        obj[item.newKey] = obj[item.oldKey];
        delete obj[item.oldKey];
    }
}
```

But I get undefined (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined) errors with my for loop.

The JSON paths can be very complex and we have to stick to this approach to have a list of old keys and new keys and iterate over each of them to dynamically fix hundreds of JSON docs.

How to write the correct `renameKeys` array and `for loop` to fix this logic?

Comment: `if(obj[item.oldKey])` will always fail for the dot notation, you'll need a recursive method that join's all previous keys with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

As implied in the question comments, the *dot notation* to access or assign deeply nested keys (e.g. `'details.name'`) does not behave as you seem to expect: in plain JavaScript / TypeScript, it just tries to access a key that is this *exact string*, i.e. *including the dot*:

```js
{
  'details.name': "some value",
}
```

...whereas you wanted:

```js
{
  details: {
    name: "some value",
  },
}
```

You can use Lodash's [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get), [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) and [`unset`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unset) utility functions to correctly translate your strings with dot notation into *paths* to potentially deeply nested keys:

> Gets the value at `path` of `object`.

> Sets the value at `path` of `object`. If a portion of path doesn't exist, it's created.

> Removes the property at `path` of `object`.

```
if (_.get(obj, item.oldKey)) {
  _.set(obj, item.newKey, _.get(obj, item.oldKey));
  _.unset(obj, item.oldKey);
}
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/tenapul/edit?js